# Громкость audio в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css3, html5, frontend

Никак не могу уменьшить громкость с помощью `html` , `javascript-om` тоже пытался, ничего не работает. Тут по хитрому сделано автовоспроизведение звука к видео, но звук стоит на максимальной громкости и сильно бьет по ушам.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: -8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1920px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.overlay-desc {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Nobile', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="ark.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" height="0" width="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<audio id="player" autoplay loop="loop">
        <source src="ark.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>

<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="ark.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
  <div class="overlay-desc">
    <h1>Coming Soon</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Для изменения громкости средствами JS следует обращаться к `audio.volume`. 
**Стоит учесть**. Громкость должна быть числом, находящимся между `0.0` и `1.0`, где `0.0` - 0%, а `1.0` - 100%.
 Громкость можно изменить как с помощью JS, так и с помощью атрибута `volume`. Его значения эквивалентны примерам выше. 
Ниже небольшой пример изменения громкости при помощи JS:

```js
let audio = document.querySelector('audio');


Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'), btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const volume = +e.target.innerText/100; // 0.5 => 50%
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.volume = volume;
    audio.play();
  });
});
```

```html
<audio>
  <source src="//cdn.ymer.pro/meow.mp3" />
</audio>

<button>50</button> <button>30</button><button>100</button> <button>5</button>
```

Пример с изменением громкости после загрузки содержимого:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
  
  audio.volume = 0.3;
}, false);
```

```html
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="//cdn.ymer.pro/meow.mp3" />
</audio>
```

Comment: Кнопки начинают работать только, после 1 проигрывания звука, как сделать, что бы без кнопок, сразу был звук 30% и с первого раза?

Comment: Кнопки начинают работать только после  проигрывания звука 1 раз, как сделать, что бы без кнопок, сразу был звук 30% и с первого раза? И еще при нажатии на кнопку, звук идёт заново, чего не должно быть т.к. он идёт параллельно с видео и получается рассинхрон.

Comment: ну так я специально сделал - `audio.currentTime = 0` устанавливает звук в `0`, это просто пример. Если хотите, чтобы звук аудио был 30% сразу после загрузки контента - устанавливайте `.volume = 0.3`  в событии `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: Добавил ещё пример.

Comment: В моем коде , это не работает. Придётся редактировать само аудио и там звук понижать.

Comment: @DOTATRASH значит делаете что-то не так. Само по себе оно не работать не может.

Comment: Тут возможно , что - то не так сделать?Попробуйте на моем коде.

Comment: В вашем примере всё работает точно также. И, к слову, зачем Вам IFrame?

Comment: Потому , что в гугл хроме запрещено автовоиспроизведение звука, а этот пример, обход этого ограничения.